# Realm.deleteFile Error: resource busy or locked

Tags: javascript, realm

I am trying to delete my database right after it's created. I'm using the following code:

```
const realm: Realm = await Realm.open(config);
realm.close();
try {
    Realm.deleteFile(config);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I get "**Error: resource busy or locked**". I know open() returns a Promise, that's why I'm using await from ES7.
The problem is that the following code works:

```
const realm: Realm = await Realm.open(config);
const e = new Date().getTime() + 1000;
while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}
realm.close();
try {
    Realm.deleteFile(config);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Meaning if a place a delay after open() everything works. Is this a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: `Realm.open()` returns a promise, not a Realm. So you don't close the Realm (`realm.close()` in your snippet doesn't close it). The second snippet will delay deleting so long that the Realm within the promise is GC'ed.

Comment: Yes, `Realm.open()` returns a promise, specifically ProgressPromise which extends Promise<Realm>. But notice I'm using `await` which means it should work without a `then` statement. Hence my question still stands.

Comment: If it is a synced Realm (can't see `config`), the sync session might take a while to finish.

Comment: Synced session? You mean is Realm currently synced with an online database? No, for now it's local.

Comment: We have recently fixed a bug in `Realm.open` (i.e., last week). I don't think it is related but I hope be happy if you could give it a shot.